# Проверка гипотезы Коллатца останавливается на двойке

Tags: python, python-3.9

Я решил проверить гипотезу [Коллатца](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0_%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%86%D0%B0) на Python.

И у меня при запуске последнее число - двойка. Если можете, помогите.

```
import time

x = 1

while True:
    is_in_cycle = False
    xn = x
    while not is_in_cycle:
        if xn % 2 == 0:
            xn = int(x / 2)
        else:
            xn = int(x * 3 + 1)
        
        if xn == 4 or xn == 2 or xn == 1:
            is_in_cycle = True
    
    print(x)
    x += 1
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: `x` и `xn` перемешаны в цикле. Тут: `xn = int(x / 2)` и ещё ниже.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Volodarskiy, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Я понял. Надо было заменить в одном месте:

```
        if xn % 2 == 0:
            xn = int(x / 2)
        else:
            xn = int(x * 3 + 1)
```

на

```
        if xn % 2 == 0:
            xn = int(xn / 2)
        else:
            xn = int(xn * 3 + 1)
```

, то есть заменить x на xn.